# Mathematica running EXTREMELY slow (freezes when plotting graphs for integrals)

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis

As part of a new subject I'm starting at school, we are required to use Mathematica instead of the more basic CAS calculators. I am currently running the V11.2 Student Edition of Mathematica.

However, after using it for almost a month, I have noticed that it performs significantly slower than my CAS calculator, especially on integrals. I have just tried multiple times to plot two integrals on the same graph using the Plot function but it freezed almost indefinitely (you could still click on it, but the CPU stays around 72% unless it is forced to quit).

The integral I was trying to plot was fairly simple, the CAS can plot it under 2 seconds. I think there must be something wrong, as I've seen much more complicated things being calculated on Mathematica.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried using it without the notebook interface, however I need to plot graphs.

```
f := 68000
m := 2340
r := 68
a[k_, t_] := f/(m + k - r*t) - 10
v[k_, t_] := Integrate[a[k, p], {p, 0, t}]
d[k_] := Integrate[v[k, p], {p, 0, k/r}]
r1 := 200
a1[k_, t_] := f/(m + k - r1*t) - 10
v1[k_, t_] := Integrate[a1[k, p], {p, 0, t}]
d1[k_] := Integrate[v1[k, p], {p, 0, k/r1}]
Plot[{d[x], d1[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

Comment: Mathematica tries to check convergence and therefore  needs to know more about your parameter k.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Is that what's causing the slow plotting? I've been currently running Mariusz's solution for 5 minutes but it doesn't seem to spitting out a graph.

Comment: @WeavingBird1917, that and also the use of `:=` without `Evaluate`. Basically the integration is done anew for each point when building the plot, I think.

Comment: @Kiro Thank you. Integrating for each point point must take a really long time. I've been trying one of the solutions posted, but it doesn't seem to be spitting a graph any time soon. I will try looking up some examples on `Evaluate`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is my take on this. Key points are the use of `Evaluate`, to make sure that `Integrate` is called only once and not every time `d` is called, and the use of `Assumptions`, where I took the liberty of assuming that `k` is real.

I hope I didn't mix up the limits.

```
{f, m, r} = {68000, 2340, 68};
a[k_, t_] := f/(m + k - r t) - 10
d[k_] := Evaluate[
   Integrate[a[k, t], {p, 0, k/r}, {t, 0, p}, 
    Assumptions -> k \[Element] Reals]];
Plot[d[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

For the other one,

```
r1 = 200;
a1[k_, t_] := f/(m + k - r1 t) - 10
d1[k_] := 
  Evaluate[Integrate[a1[k, t], {p, 0, k/r1}, {t, 0, p}, 
    Assumptions -> k \[Element] Reals]];
Plot[d1[x], {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you even need `:=` delayed assignment if your right-hand part is `Evaluate`d?

Comment: @Ruslan Good point, the delayed assignment is not doing anything and we might just as well use `=`. Also, due to `Evaluate` one should take care that `k` has not been given any values to get the expected output.

Comment: If you want to be super safe, you should protect `t` and `p`, too: `Block[{k, p, t}, d[k_] = Integrate[a[k, t], {p, 0, k/r}, {t, 0, p}, Assumptions -> k \[Element] Reals]; ]`

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
$Version
(* "11.2.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"]; Remove["Global`*"];(* Clears All variables *)

f = 68000;
m = 2340;
r = 68;
a[k_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := f/(m + k - r*t) - 10
v[k_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a[k, p], {p, 0, t}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]; 
d[k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[v[k, p], {p, 0, k/r}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
r1 := 200
a1[k_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := f/(m + k - r1*t) - 10
v1[k_?NumericQ, t_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[a1[k, p], {p, 0, t}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]
d1[k_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[v1[k, p], {p, 0, k/r1}, Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]

Plot[{d[x], d1[x]}, {x, 0, 10}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

Comment: @WeavingBird1917.In my 3 years old laptop, about 3.7 seconds.

Comment: Thank you! I opened it in a new notebook and it plotted almost instantaneously! I marked Kiro's as the answer because he goes through some points that would be helpful for newcomers, however this method works perfectly too.

Answer (score 5):

Aside from necessary `Assumptions` mentioned in another answers, your problem is that you're abusing delayed assignment — the `:=` operator. It results in the right-hand side being evaluated *every* time you call your function or use your variable — unless the right-hand side has been wrapped with `Evaluate` function. I.e., `Integrate` functions are re-evaluating the integrals each time you call your `v`, `d`, `v1` and `d1` functions.

The proper way, after adding the necessary `Assumptions` for the integrals is to replace your `:=` with `=` — at least for the calls to `Integrate`, although in your specific case you don't need delayed assignment at all, so you could simply replace all of the operators with immediate assignments.

Now, if you know that your variable $k$ in the whole computation satisfies $k\in\mathbb R$, then you can wrap the computation in [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) function or just set [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions.html) variable to your assumption at the beginning. (Don't forget to reset the variable later to the default value of `True` when you do unrelated calculations.)

After taking all this into account, your code could look like this:

```
f = 68000;
m = 2340;
r = 68;
r1 = 200;
a[k_, t_] = f/(m + k - r*t) - 10;
a1[k_, t_] = f/(m + k - r1*t) - 10;
Assuming[Element[k, Reals],
 v[k_, t_] = Integrate[a[k, p], {p, 0, t}];
 d[k_] = Integrate[v[k, p], {p, 0, k/r}];
 v1[k_, t_] = Integrate[a1[k, p], {p, 0, t}];
 d1[k_] = Integrate[v1[k, p], {p, 0, k/r1}];
 Plot[{d[x], d1[x]}, {x, 0, 10}]
]
```

> [image: output of the code above]

More on `:=` and `=` assignments see in [Immediate and Delayed Definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve your problem more directly

```
Clear[f,m,r]
Integrate[f/(m + k - r*t) - 10, {t, 0, k/r}, {p, 0, t},Assumptions ->{Element[{m, k}, Reals], k > 0, m > 0}]
(* -((k (f + 5 k) + f (k + m) Log[m/(k + m)])/r^2) *)
Plot[% /. {f -> 68000, m -> 2340, r -> 68}, {k, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Integrate[f/(m + k - r*t) - 10, {p, 0, k/r}, {t, 0, p}]`?

Comment: ups my answer was given to fast,  thank you